# Remove duplicate from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

The database type is PostGres 8.3.

If I wrote:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, count(*) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3 having count(*) > 1;
```

I have some rows that have a count over 1. How can I take out the duplicate (I do still want 1 row for each of them instead of +1 row... I do not want to delete them all.)

Example:

```
1-2-3
1-2-3
1-2-3
2-3-4
4-5-6
```

Should become :

```
1-2-3
2-3-4
4-5-6
```

*The only answer I found is [there](http://www.siafoo.net/article/64) but I am wondering if I could do it without hash column.*

**Warning**
I do not have a PK with an unique number so I can't use the technique of min(...). The PK is the 3 fields.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand it right. You say "The PK is the 3 fields" - then how come you have duplicates in the table like multiple 1-2-3 records. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The PK was in the 3 fields, we had to remove them for a merge (long story) now we need to put it back. We have some duplicate that we would like to take off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of many reasons that all tables should have a primary key (not necessarily an ID number or IDENTITY, but a combination of one or more columns that uniquely identifies a row and which has its uniqueness enforced in the database).

Your best bet is something like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, count(*) 
INTO temp_table1
FROM table1
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3 having count(*) > 1

DELETE T1
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT field1, field2, field3
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY field1, field2, field3 having count(*) > 1) SQ ON
            SQ.field1 = T1.field1 AND
            SQ.field2 = T1.field2 AND
            SQ.field3 = T1.field3

INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM temp_table1

DROP TABLE temp_table1
```

Comment: I am currently trying your suggestion. +1

Comment: It works thx, I have modified few thing like DELETE T1 doesnt work, I had to put the T1 after FROM table1 as T1. Few things like that. But the solution was fast and successful here.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you. Thanks for pointing out my overlooking the T1 alias. I've corrected it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is:

```
CREATE <temporary table> (<correct structure for table being cleaned>);
BEGIN WORK;   -- if needed
INSERT INTO <temporary table> SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <source table>;
DELETE FROM <source table>
INSERT INTO <source table> SELECT * FROM <temporary table>;
COMMIT WORK;  -- needed
DROP <temporary table>;
```

I'm not sure whether the 'work' is needed on transaction statements, nor whether the explicit BEGIN is necessary in PostgreSQL.  But the concept applies to any DBMS.

The only thing to beware of is referential constraints and in particular triggered delete operations.  If those exist, this may prove less satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

This will use the [OID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html) Object ID (if the table was created with it):

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE OID NOT IN (SELECT   MIN (OID)
                              FROM table1
                          GROUP BY field1, field2, field3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I should misunderstand something but I'll say :

SELECT **DISTINCT** field1, field2, field3 FROM table1

Too easy to be good? ^^

Comment: I think Daok wants to delete all but one of the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Using TSQL, no idea if Postgres supports temp tables but you could select into a temp table, and then loop through and delete and insert your results back into the original

```
-- **Disclaimer** using TSQL
-- You could select your records into a temp table with a pk
Create Table #dupes
([id] int not null identity(1,1), f1 int, f2 int, f3 int)

Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (1,2,3)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (1,2,3)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (1,2,3)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (2,3,4)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (4,5,6)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (4,5,6)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (4,5,6)
Insert Into #dupes (f1,f2,f3) values (7,8,9)

Select f1,f2,f3 From #dupes

Declare @rowCount int
Declare @counter int
Set @counter = 1
Set @rowCount = (Select Count([id]) from #dupes)

while (@counter < @rowCount + 1)
    Begin
       Delete From #dupes
       Where [Id] <> 
            (Select [id] From #dupes where [id]=@counter)
                and
            (
                [f1] = (Select [f1] from #dupes where [id]=@counter)
                and
                [f2] = (Select [f2] from #dupes where [id]=@counter)
                and
                [f3] = (Select [f3] from #dupes where [id]=@counter)
            )
       Set @counter = @counter + 1
    End

Select f1,f2,f3 From #dupes -- You could take these results and pump them back into --your original table

Drop Table #dupes
```

Tested this on MS SQL Server 2000. Not familiar with Postgres' options but maybe this will lead you in a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method I've found:

Postgre SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT distinct * FROM table1
truncate table table1
insert into table1 select * from tmp
drop table tmp
```

T-SQL syntax:

```
select distinct * into #tmp from table1
truncate table table1
insert into table1 select * from #tmp
drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

A good [Answer](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1103) for this problem, but for SQL Server. It uses the ROWCOUNT that SQL Server offers, to good effect. I have never used PostgreSQL and hence don't know the equivalent of ROWCOUNT in PostgreSQL.