# Eliminating Duplicate rows in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to remove duplicate rows return from a SELECT Query in Postgres

I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM names ORDER BY name
```

But this somehow does not eliminate duplicate rows?

Comment: I'm using an ancient PostgreSQL 7.3.4 version

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate from a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243567/remove-duplicate-from-a-table)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. @Flimzy ... a different question, with a fairly vague title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL is case sensitive, this might be a problem here
DISTINCT ON can be used for case-insensitive search (tested on 7.4)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (upper(name)) name FROM names ORDER BY upper(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something with same-looking-but-different characters (like LATIN 'a'/CYRILLIC 'а')

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add a trim() on that too. Or else 'Record' and 'Record ' will be treated as separate entities. That ended up hurting me at first, I had to update my query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (upper(trim(name))) name FROM names ORDER BY upper(trim(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 9.2 and greater you can now cast the column to a CITEXT type or even make the column that so you don't have to cast on select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name::citext FROM names ORDER BY name::citext
```