# TypeORM select with case insensitive distinct

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to create a TypeORM query builder that connects to a postgresql DB to get all unique names in the DB. My query looks like this

```
names = await this._context.manager
        .getRepository(Names)
        .createQueryBuilder('names')
        .select('DISTINCT ON (names.name) names.name')
        .orderBy('names.name', 'ASC')
        .getRawMany();
```

Right now this query fetches all names in the DB but it's case sensitive so it can't sort out duplicates like 'Jane Doe' from 'jane doe'. So far i've tried to make the distinct upper/lowercase like this:
`.select('DISTINCT ON LOWER(names.name) names.name')` but that doesn't work. I also found a .distinctOn() function but i couldn't make that case insensitive either.

I'm new to typeORM so i'm at a bit of a loss on where to go from here, any ideas?

I'm working in Node.JS towards a postgresql DB if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subject of this issue is postgres rather than typeORM.
Similar question: [Eliminating Duplicate rows in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152322/eliminating-duplicate-rows-in-postgres).

In your case the correct syntax is:

```
names = await this._context.manager
        .getRepository(Names)
        .createQueryBuilder('names')
        .select('DISTINCT ON (LOWER(names.name)) names.name')
        .orderBy('LOWER(names.name)', 'ASC')
        .getRawMany();
```

Comment: Yeah this works like a charm :) I tried the LOWER before but i missed adding it to the orderBy as well so i didn't get any results. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

With Repository, I did the case insensitive search with postgres as database using `ILIKE` operator in this way

```
const planning_groups: any[] =
    await this.planningGroupRepository.find({
        where: `"tenant_id" ILIKE '${tenantId}'` 
    });
```

where **tenant_id** is a column name and `tenantId` is a keyword to search for.

Comment: How do you write this to search on a column of a relation?

Comment: This doesn't work for me ("typeorm": "^0.3.17",) `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<ENTITY> | FindOptionsWhere<ENTITY>[] | undefined'.ts(2322)`