# How to make case-insensitive sorting by field without changing original data from selection

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I face a problem where I need to sort by table field in a case-insensitive order but without modifying it in a selection.

I have data like this in my table.

| Song | Band | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event Horizon | Wildways | Metalcore |
| Doppelganger | palach | Rap |
| Gone With the Wind | Architects | Metalcore |
| Chelsea's Smile | Bring Me the Horizon | Death core |
| 1984 | Louna | Alternative rock |
| Bye-bye kitty | playingtheangel | Rap |
| Deliverance | DSHMC | Metalcore |
| Anyway | Magnum | Rap |
| crybaby | aikko | Rap |

I have a model like

```
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('Song')
export class SongEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'Name',
  })
  public name: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'Band',
  })
  public band: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'Genre',
  })
  public genre: string;
}
```

I want to be able to sort data in a case-insensitive mode but leave data as is. For example, when I sort in by `band` in ascending mode, using the following code.

```
songRepository.find({
    order: {
        band: "ASC",
    }
})
```

I want to receive the following output.

| Band |
| --- |
| aikko |
| Architects |
| Bring Me the Horizon |
| DSHMC |
| Louna |
| Magnum |
| palach |
| playingtheangel |
| Wildways |

However, I receive the next output, because bands are sorted in a case-sensitive mode.

| Band |
| --- |
| Architects |
| Bring Me the Horizon |
| DSHMC |
| Louna |
| Magnum |
| Wildways |
| aikko |
| palach |
| playingtheangel |

In plain SQL, it's possible to use via lowering field in order condition https://stackoverflow.com/a/2413436/6625548. However, I don't see any option in [docs](https://typeorm.io/find-options) on how to do it via entity repository in the find condition.

What is the right way to do case-insensitive ordering in typeorm?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option. You could do it via queryBuilder like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897893/6459327 If `LOWER` is not available there is probably a similiar method in your database system `const songs = await songRepository.createQueryBuilder('songs').select('songs').orderBy('LOWER(names.band)', 'ASC').getMany();`

Comment: Use Case-Insensitive [collation for sorting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-84F2A594-E641-4436-A903-D5D5B4D7FFA9). See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5b9b8b152ba419dbd9f47a2980176856)

Comment: @astentx looks cool. Thanks for sharing. However, the previous option is easier to implement via typeorm.

Comment: @Enak, Thanks a lot! I've implemented it in that way. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: @PavloZhukov Yes, for a single query `lower` is simpler. If you want to setup case-insensitive or accent-insensitive comparison for the overall session, NLS option may be a single entry point of setup

Comment: @astentx, thanks for the details. An excellent point! I'll discuss this part with a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment as full answer:

TypeORM does not have an option for this.

Similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897893/6459327, you can use `QueryBuilder` and integrated function of your database to compare and sort everything lower-case.

```js
const songs = await songRepository.createQueryBuilder('songs').select('songs').orderBy('LOWER(songs.band)', 'ASC').getMany();
```