# Select Distinct (case insensitive) on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152322/eliminating-duplicate-rows-in-postgres) and a few other places before but seems like the suggested answers either don't apply to postgres or don't work in this situation.

I'm looking to select distinct column names, eg:

`SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name WHERE ... ORDER BY column_name` however I'm looking to eliminate case sensitive duplicates (eg `A` and `a` should be considered the same thing)

I tried `COLLATE` but all available formats were case sensitive. And changing case via `LOWER()` OR `UPPER()` wont work because In this situation I need the case information.

I thought about something like this to grab unique values but still maintain the case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT upper(my_column) as upper_case, my_column
FROM my_table
ORDER BY upper(my_column)
```

But introducing my_column in the distinct query negates the whole thing.

How can I get unique values (case insensitive) without modifying the case of the results itself?

Comment: Would something like `SELECT DISTINCT ON (upper(my_column)) my_column` work? (Edited to fix syntax)

Comment: BTW, have you looked at [the accepted answer on the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152371/683329)? It's literally this problem, for this database, returning exactly what you're asking for? You may need to clarify your question if this is not what you're after...

Comment: You're right. This does the trick. I misread the answer there. I thought it was just `DISTINCT` not `DISTINCT ON`

Comment: No worries; easy distinction to miss :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PostgreSQL (but not many other databases), you can use a DISTINCT ON clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (upper(my_column)) my_column
FROM my_table
ORDER BY upper(my_column)
```

You can even choose which of the results you get, by adding another column to the ORDER BY clause to make the desired result appear first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (upper(my_column)) my_column
FROM my_table
ORDER BY upper(my_column), other_column
```

Documentation: [DISTINCT Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT MAX(my_column)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY upper(my_column);
```

This returns one value.  If you want all the values:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT my_column)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY upper(my_column);
```