# How to remove duplicates in a table?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE join_table {
  id1 integer,
  id2 integer
}
```

I want to create a `UNIQ CONSTRAINT(id1, id2)`, however, I am seeing some bad data such as this:

```
id1   | id2
------------
1     | 1
1     | 1
1     | 2
```

So, the record (1,1) is clearly a duplicate, and will violate uniq constraint. How do I write a sql query which will remove all duplicate records from the table.

Note: I want to delete one of the duplicates so that I can create the uniq constraint

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate from a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243567/remove-duplicate-from-a-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will keep one of the duplicates:

```
delete from join_table
where ctid not in (select min(ctid)
                   from join_table
                   group by id1, id2);
```

Your table doesn't have a unique identifier that could be used to "pick one survivor". That's where Postgres' `ctid` comes in handy, as it is an internal unique identifier for each row. Note that you should never use the `ctid` for more than just a single statement. It is not a universally unique things but for the runtime of a single statement it's just fine.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dabfc/1

If you want to get rid of *all* rows that are duplicated:

```
delete from join_table
where (id1, id2) in (select id1, id2
                     from join_table
                     group by id1, id2
                     having count(*) > 1);
```

Neither solution will be fast on a large table. Creating a new table without duplicates as jjanes has shown will be much faster if you need a substantial number of rows from a large table.

Answer (score 2):

Without a primary key, that will be hard to do.

Is the existing table named in FK constraints and such?  If not, just remake it.

```
begin;
create table new_table as select distinct * from join_table;
drop table join_table;
alter table new_table rename TO join_table;
commit;
```