# How does LIMIT interact with DELETE by primary key in Postgres? (Fix corrupt unique index)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, corruption, unique-index

I've been handed a database that's stuck in a weird state. At some indeterminate time in the past, I ended up in a situation where I had duplicate rows in the same table with the same primary key:

```
=> \d my_table
Table "public.my_table"
       Column       |          Type           | Modifiers 
--------------------+-------------------------+-----------
 id                 | bigint                  | not null
 some_data          | bigint                  | 
 a_string           | character varying(1024) | not null
Indexes:
"my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

=> SELECT id, count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1 ORDER BY id;
#50-some results, non-consecutive rows.
```

I have no idea how the database got into this state, but I want to be able to safely get out of it. If, for each duplicated primary key, if I execute a query of the form:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = "a_duplicated_row" LIMIT 1;
```

Is it only going to delete *one* row from the table, or is it going to delete both rows with the given primary key?

Comment: As far as I know, the SQL you have entered is not valid - [the Postgres manual page for `DELETE` statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html) makes no mention of a `LIMIT` clause. So the answer to the immediate question is "neither, it will error". The answer to the implicit question of "how to delete one row of a pair of duplicates" can be found elsewhere.

Comment: The title of the question should be more like "How to fix a corrupted unique index"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, PostgreSQL does not yet implement LIMIT for DELETE or UPDATE.  If the rows are indistinguishable in every other way, you will need to carefully use the hidden `ctid` column to break ties, like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181875/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-a-table/22182338).  Or just create the table by selecting distinct tuples from the existing table, and renaming.

Comment: @AndrewRueckert  Also, read http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption . Before you do anything else, you should *make a backup* - preferably both a filesystem level copy (pg_basebackup) and a logical dump with `pg_dump`. Once you've fixed the conflict you should reindex, then start some serious investigation about the possible cause.